# access array in sql google BigQuery

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

Currently, I have an array of objects in one of the attributes of my table

```
table metadata{
    String id,
    repeated Point points
}

table Point{
    String x,
    String y
}
```

When I do

```
select id, points from metadata
```

in Google BigQuery

I get data in the format

```
[
  {
    "id": "453ee599-0e74-4098-bda5-9808953cf757",
    "points": [
      {
        "x": "x_",
        "y": "y1_"
      },
      {
        "x": "x2_",
        "y": "y2_",
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How should I modify my sql query such that results are in the format

```
[
  {
    "id": "453ee599-0e74-4098-bda5-9808953cf757",
    "x" : "x1_",
    "y" : "y1_",
  },
  {
    "id": "453ee599-0e74-4098-bda5-9808953cf757",
    "x" : "x2_",
    "y" : "y2_",
  }
]
```

Comment: i read your post and can't understand your data structure. could you provide a dbfiddle example?

Comment: @user3285099 - consider voting up on answers that helped and accept the one you consider helped the most!

Answer (score 2):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, point.* 
FROM `project.dataset.metadata`, 
UNNEST(points) point
```

If to apply to sample data from your question  -

result is

```
Row id                                      x   y    
1   453ee599-0e74-4098-bda5-9808953cf757    x_  y_   
2   453ee599-0e74-4098-bda5-9808953cf757    x2_ y2_
```

or if present in JSON

```
[
  {
    "id": "453ee599-0e74-4098-bda5-9808953cf757",
    "x": "x_",
    "y": "y_"
  },
  {
    "id": "453ee599-0e74-4098-bda5-9808953cf757",
    "x": "x2_",
    "y": "y2_"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to unnest:

```sql
select id, point
from metadata,
unnest(points) as point
```

See the [working with arrays documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#flattening-arrays)